# XCode Instruments can't let me choose target

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, instruments, target

My Instruments suddenly can't let me Choose Target. Normally, if I move my mouse to "Choose Target", then a list of available targets will show up and let me select.

But today, I opened my instruments, and move my mouse to "Choose Target", the instruments hangs forever and occupied full CPU. And since then, every time it happens like that, no matter I restarted my mac, restarted xcode, restarted everything. And even, I uninstalled XCode 4.02, and installed fresh copy of XCode 4.1, I still can't Choose Target in instruments.

Any one can help?

Pic is here

[image]

Comment: It shows to me if I wait 5 seconds

Comment: well, for me, it won't. and the CPU was highest then and the instruments app just hang. I have to force quit it.